# How many dice do I get when I spend willpower on a chance roll?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

> If your dice pool is ever reduced to zero or fewer dice, you can still make a "chance roll."

A chance roll gives me one die.  If I spend willpower on that roll, does it bump me up to four dice?  Or do I start from whatever pool ended up giving me the chance die to begin with and *then* add three?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You add three dice to your *original pool*, not to the chance die.

From the section on Willpower, p. 132:

> Willpower should be spent and three dice are added to your dice pool before all penalties for your roll have been applied. So, form your pool, add all bonuses — including your three dice from Willpower — and then subtract all penalties. **Yes, that means if penalties are sufficiently extreme, you could be reduced to a chance roll even if you have spent Willpower for three extra dice.**

(Emphasis mine.)

In fact, the example in the book involves just this situation and concludes, *"You must make a chance roll for your character to succeed, even though you spent Willpower on the task."*